# Array.filter() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filtering, minimize

I am trying to compress a code snippet that I have in JS regarding the `array.filter()` method. I would like to filter beers according to their category, which I have made work with the code below. However, I would prefer to not repeat myself as much as I have and thus find a simpler/shorter way to display the same code.

```
<div id="filters">
  <button class="filterButton">Types of beer</button>
  <div class="filterOptions">
    <li class="filter" data-action="filter" data-filter="IPA">IPA</li>
    <li class="filter" data-action="filter" data-filter="Hefeweizen">
      Hefeweizen
    </li>
    <li class="filter" data-action="filter" data-filter="Oktoberfest">
      Oktoberfest
    </li>
    <li class="filter" data-action="filter" data-filter="European Lager">
      European Lager
    </li>
    <li class="filter" data-action="filter" data-filter="Stout">Stout</li>
    <li class="filter" data-action="filter" data-filter="Belgian Specialty Ale">
      Belgian Specialty Ale
    </li>
    <li class="filter" data-action="filter" data-filter="California Common">
      California Common
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function setFilters() {
  //show filters:
  document.querySelector(".filterButton").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.toggle("showFilters");
  });
  //event listeners:
  document
    .querySelector("[data-filter='IPA']")
    .addEventListener("click", filterIPA);
  document
    .querySelector("[data-filter='Hefeweizen']")
    .addEventListener("click", filterHefe);
  document
    .querySelector("[data-filter='Oktoberfest']")
    .addEventListener("click", filterOkt);
  document
    .querySelector("[data-filter='European Lager']")
    .addEventListener("click", filterEuro);
  document
    .querySelector("[data-filter='Stout']")
    .addEventListener("click", filterStout);
  document
    .querySelector("[data-filter='Belgian Specialty Ale']")
    .addEventListener("click", filterBelgian);
  document
    .querySelector("[data-filter='California Common']")
    .addEventListener("click", filterCalif);
  document
    .querySelector("[data-sort='alc']")
    .addEventListener("click", sortAlc);
  document.querySelector(".resetFilter").addEventListener("click", resetFilter);
}

function filterIPA() {
  console.log(allBeers);
  let ipaBeers = allBeers.filter(function (IPA) {
    return IPA.category == "IPA";
  });
  displayBeer(ipaBeers);
  getPrices();
  document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.remove("showFilters");
}

function filterHefe() {
  console.log(allBeers);
  let hefeBeers = allBeers.filter(function (hefe) {
    return hefe.category == "Hefeweizen";
  });
  displayBeer(hefeBeers);
  getPrices();
  document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.remove("showFilters");
}

function filterOkt() {
  console.log(allBeers);
  let oktBeers = allBeers.filter(function (okt) {
    return okt.category == "Oktoberfest";
  });
  displayBeer(oktBeers);
  getPrices();
  document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.remove("showFilters");
}

function filterEuro() {
  console.log(allBeers);
  let euroBeers = allBeers.filter(function (euro) {
    return euro.category == "European Lager";
  });
  displayBeer(euroBeers);
  getPrices();
  document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.remove("showFilters");
}

function filterStout() {
  console.log(allBeers);
  let stoutBeers = allBeers.filter(function (stout) {
    return stout.category == "Stout";
  });
  displayBeer(stoutBeers);
  getPrices();
  document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.remove("showFilters");
}

function filterBelgian() {
  console.log(allBeers);
  let belgianBeers = allBeers.filter(function (belgian) {
    return belgian.category == "Belgian Specialty Ale";
  });
  displayBeer(belgianBeers);
  getPrices();
  document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.remove("showFilters");
}

function filterCalif() {
  console.log(allBeers);
  let califBeers = allBeers.filter(function (calif) {
    return calif.category == "California Common";
  });
  displayBeer(califBeers);
  getPrices();
  document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.remove("showFilters");
}

function resetFilter() {
  location.reload();
}
```

Comment: The markup is invalid. `<li>` elements are only allowed to be direct childs of `<ol>` or `<ul>` elements

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this correctly, could you make a generic `filterBeer` function that accepts the category you would like to filter by?

Something like this:

```js
function filterBeer(category) {
  console.log(allBeers);
  let beers = allBeers.filter(function (b) {
    return b.category == category;
  });
  displayBeer(beers);
  getPrices();
  document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.remove("showFilters");
}
```

Comment: The `filterX` functions are used as event handlers, you could make use of that fact (and `this`) -> `function filterBeer() { const category = this.dataset("filter"); ... }` and then use `filterBeer` for all the `click` events

Answer (score 1):

All of your functions are exactly identical except for variable names and the hardcoded category.

This is the most simplest form of refactoring: extract the common elements to a function and make the one element that *does* vary a *parameter* into that function. Like this:

```
function filterBeer(category) {
  console.log(allBeers);
  let beers = allBeers.filter(function (beer) {
    return beer.category == category;
  });
  displayBeer(beers);
  getPrices();
  document.querySelector(".filterOptions").classList.remove("showFilters");
}
```

You can then ditch every single one of your existing functions and use this instead. Of course, you need to edit your `click` listeners to call the function with a parameter instead of just standalone. Like this:

```
document.querySelector("[data-filter='IPA']").addEventListener("click", function() { filterBeer("IPA") });
document.querySelector("[data-filter='Hefeweizen']").addEventListener("click", function() { filterBeer("Hefeweizen") });
//etc
```

However, I notice also that there is redundancy here too. The argument to `filterBeer` is exactly equal in each case to the `data-filter` being queried. You can make a function here too.

```
function addFilterClick(category) {
  document.querySelector("[data-filter='" + category + "']")
    .addEventListener("click", function() { filterBeer(category) });
}
```

With this function you can simplify your `setFilters` function to this:

```
addFilterClick("IPA");
addFilterClick("Hefeweizen");
//etc
```

But *even this* can be simplified further, as you're repeating the same function call on a series of different strings. You can make an array and loop over it:

```
var categories = [ "IPA", "Hefeweizen", "Oktoberfest", "European Lager", ... ];
for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++)
  addFilterClick(categories[i]);
```

At that point you can get rid of `addFilterClick` and just put the `document.querySelector` line back, since you'd only be using `addFilterClick` in one place.

Comment: `setFilters()` only adds the event handlers so the markup is already there - including the `data-filter` attribute. Why don't you just use the already available markup (which is maybe controlled by the server) with all its properties (order, value, number of beers, ...). With your setup you would need `categories.length` "empty" `<li>` elements which get filled from an array in JS. If there's a new beer you would have to change two places (array + markup) instead of only adding a new `<li data-filter="new beer" />` element

Comment: @Andreas To be perfectly honest, I'm a node.js dev and don't touch html, so that would require figuring out the correct query to get a list of elements and whatever properties and functions to get the `data-filter` - you're definitely right that it would be better though.

Comment: @Klaycon Thank you so much for your help, I had some issues on how to make the generic function work for each category but I get it now!